# Encrypt the file content

Tags: winforms, encryption, c#-3.0

I am working on a C# winform application. Currently I am getting an xml file along with the exe in bin folder. This xml file contains credentials of Database server. I want to hide it.

Can I encrypt the file content in Post build event or any other way to do it? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read about the native support for Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This question although interesting is not strictly on topic. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't see why this question might be off-topic. It might be too broad, but I don't have the necessary expertise to evaluate that.